# Django связь моделей

Tags: python, django

недавно начала использовать django, не могу понять следующее:

models.py

```
class Room (models.Model):
     nameroom = models.CharField(max_length=20) 
     price = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Цена',blank=True, null=True)
     notes = models.TextField(verbose_name='Примечания', blank=True, null=True)

class Application (models.Model):
     DocDate = models.DateField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Дата документа')
     Person = models.ForeignKey(CharField(max_length=120)
     Apartments = models.ForeignKey(Rooms, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
     Price = ????????
```

Так вот вопрос, как мне в модель Application получить поле price из модели Room?

Comment: зачем его получать в другой модели?

Comment: Поскольку вам нужно получить конкретную цену для конкретного экземпляра класса Application, вам необходимо описать функцию, которая получает соответствующие данные. Просто объявлением какого-то поля модели здесь не обойтись.